# Grape, sending JSON as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-grape

My Grape API accepts json format and I have method that accepts JSON as parameter:

```
desc 'JSON test'
params do
  requires :json, type: JSON
end
post :json_test do
  json = params[:json]
  {result: json}
end
```

When I make request via postman, parameters are raw with application/json content type:

```
{
   "json": {"test": "test"}
}
```

When I send this I get error message:

```
"json is invalid"
```

However, when I send it like this:

```
{
  "json": "{\"test\": \"test\"}"
}
```

It shows me correct response:

```
{
 "result": {
   "test": "test"
  }
}
```

Why this is happening? When I make type `Hash` the first variant works, but if I want to send `Array` of hashes/jsons? I kniw that Grape does not support `Array[Hash]` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*grape parses the application/json data before it reaches your params block.*

---

in this block:

```
params do
  requires :json, type: JSON
end
```

you are telling grape that your :json param should contain a JSON string.

so when you send this:

```
{
   "json": {"test": "test"}
}
```

json contains

```
{"test": "test"}
```

which is sees as a **hash**, not a valid JSON string hence our error.

but when you send this

```
{
  "json": "{\"test\": \"test\"}"
}
```

json contains

```
"{\"test\": \"test\"}"
```

which is a valid JSON string, which it will then happily parse into a hash for you.

---

If you want to use

```
{
   "json": {"test": "test"}
}
```

in your post request, Your params block should be something like this:

```
params do
    requires :json, type: Hash #<-- Hash here instead of JSON since json data has already been parsed into a Hash
end
```

Comment: This works. However, if I want to send array of json objects it won't work, because Grape does not have `Array[Hash]`, only `Array[JSON]` type.

Comment: instead of "Array[Hash]" you will just use "Array", as the documentation states that type: Array treats nested parameters as "values of hashes in an array". If you use type Array[JSON] then the param you are specifying the type of must be a valid json string as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse a classic JSON with Grape using this:

```
params do
  requires :groceries, type: JSON
end
```

then send a JSON with a **single** *key*, that has a *value* of type String (a JSON String).

**Examples for sending the JSON:**

*Use as raw parameter:*

```
{ "groceries_key": "{\"fruits\": { \"apples\": 2 }, \"vegetables\": { \"carrets\": \"a few\" }}" }
```

*Use in a HTTP GET request:*

```
http://localhost/api/test?groceries=<the_above_raw_parameter_without_whitespaces>
```

**Examples for parsing the JSON:**

The *value* is a JSON String, and to parse it, use

```
get do    
  JSON.parse (params['groceries']['groceries_key'])
end
```

which will give you a nice json:

```
{
  "fruits": {
    "apples": 2
  },
  "vegetables": {
    "carrets": "a few"
  }
}
```

versions used:

```
gem 'grape',         '0.14.0'
gem 'grape-swagger', '0.20.2'
ruby 1.9.3p545
```